# How to highlight a road segment in my map?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have a table in QGIS that has 2 columns that I use to create road segments, StreetID and SegmntID. This creates a unique ID for each road segment. For example, for a road named Maine St, which I associated a 1 to identify, there might be 3 segments. So each segment will have a unique ID of 1-1, 1-2 and 1-3. I am going to print one sheet for each road segment. In Composer Manager, I have each sheet set up where you see that specific street segment in the middle of the map but you also see the ends of other segments attached to it in the same map view. I would like to be able to highlight that specific segment for that sheet so that it is obvious that that is the segment for that sheet. How would I set that up in the Composer Manager?

Answer (score 5):

U got to use the **atlas generation feature** of QGIS. The "coverage layer" will be your road segments layer.
Then u can apply a rule-based symbology on your segments layer where u highlight the "current" atlas feature. To do so u can use a rule such as `id=atlasfeatureid` and apply the awaited style on this rule ... (and another for `id<>atlasfeatureid`).

Comment: Segments is not a layer, it's only and attribute in the table.

Comment: U got to have road segments **geometry** in any case ... how do u associate roads and segments then ? in the example u give your layer should be a segments layer that build a street when sharing the same (street) id ...

Comment: Roads is my layer. In the table for that layer, I have 2 attributes, StreetID and SegmentID. I used those 2 attributes to label my road segments, segment id. Now in the composer manager, I have sheets created for each segment id by generating an atlas. In the atlas generation, I chose my Roads layer as the coverage layer. In the map showing that segment id, it also includes other segments that are attached to that specific segment. I want the specific segment to be highlighted on the sheet.

Comment: How do u label your roads segments if u don't have their geometry ? U did all "by hand" ? If a road has 5 segments where do u store these 5 informations ?

Comment: Two columns were added in the attributes table, StreetID and SegmentID. The numbers were entered by hand.

Comment: Check out the detailed instructions in the answer to this question: gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221788